# Physical vs logical files in Git local repo

Tags: git, git-remote, repo

I am trying to understand Git workflows. If for example I see following random pictures taken from on the net:

[Git workflow 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dosaA.png)

[Git workflow 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pT6A.png)

[Git workflow 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeVCr.png)

They show a Remote directory and 3 Local directories namely Working dir, Staging area and Local Repo. So far what I have understood is that all the 3 local directories are the names of physically 1 directory, the one where I have cloned the remote repo for example. While I can switch this local repo into 3 different logical states, namely working dir, staging area and local repo.

Please correct me if I am wrong in this understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain to you in simple words with the help of an image;

[image]

The local file system where git resides in your local machine is called as **Local Repository**. Let say it as a collection of everything, which resides in your computer.

Now, when you switch to one branch, you will be able to access / see files belonging to that branch. These files are present to you **virtually**. Which means, all files associated with other branches are hidden (not like hidden files) from you and you are presented with some files only. Lets say, the **Local repository** contains all files, but everything other than that particular branch are hidden from your eyes. Now, the area where you see all these files are called **Workspace**. So, for your understanding, lets say **Local Repository + Branch = Workspace / Working directory**.

Again, when you make changes to files in a branch, they are temporarily saved (staged) before permanently saving (commit) it. You may add / remove / modify files in that area before finalizing your changes. This space is called as an **index**.

Once you commit your changes, your files will be permanently stored in a branch, and that location where those files resides is called **Local Repository**.

Comment: does it mean the same thing as I stated in my post or was my understanding not correct?

Comment: let us say I am checkout on branch A of my local repo and I have 10 files in this branch. Also I have another branch B in this git repo which has only 5 files in it. When I switch to branch B from branch A and I goto my git repo folder on my filesystem then how many files will i see over there, 10 or 5?

Comment: @Marina you will see only 5 files corresponding to branch B. Also, if you find my answer helpful, please don't forget to upvote and (or) to accept it.

Comment: I just learnt that .git directory means the 'Local repository'. This helps me to understand your answer now. Maybe you can include this info in your answer as well.

Comment: Is it correct to say that "Index" is also inside the "Local repository" or in other words .git directory?

Comment: @Marina yes, Index is also inside Local repository. In short, there is nothing lying outside local repository.